# UsageError: Line magic function `%` not found. Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am getting an error on the following line in my Jupyter Notebook

```
% matplotlib inline
```

I am using Python version 3.7, ipython version 7.0.1

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Spell it as two words, rather than three:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Okay, this works, but why? In my testing it was Unix that accepted the 3 and Windows that accepted it as two. If this is true across all cases, what is it about Win. vs Linix/Unix with jupyter that causes this error?

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.8 and iPython 7.19, it actually needs two words, and not three.

Comment: Thanks! I am just doing a Udacity tutorial and in the tutorial, they use the "wrong" version (`% matplotlib inline`).

Comment: What's the difference between `%matplotlib` and `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: %matplotlib displays in a separate window, while inline keeps it within your Jupyter notebook.